# MissingPropertyException: No such property: request for class: Script1

Tags: java, groovyshell

How to run a groovy script in java from a servlet? With the below code, I have a

> MissingPropertyException: No such property: request for class: Script1

This is my script

```
<script type="server/groovy">
        import com.daimler.Car
        def id = request.getParameter("id")
        car = Car.lookup(id)
    </script>
```

This is my Java code

```
public void runScript(HttpServletRequest request) {

Script script = groovyShell.parse("def id = request.getParameter(\"id\")\n" +
"        car = Car.lookup(id)");

        Map bindings = script.getBinding().getVariables();

        bindings.put("id",1);
        Object ret = script.run(); //a+b+3

        //and if you changed variables in script you can get their values 
        Object aAfter = bindings.get("car"); 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the HttpServletRequest request object in the bindings as well:

`Map bindings = script.getBinding().getVariables();
bindings.put("id",1);
bindings.put("request", request);
Object ret = script.run(); //a+b+3 (...)`